# traefik v2.2 help using only docker-compose router service entrypoint

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

Started learning about docker, traefik for playing in home.

Aim: Put everything all together in `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` files, understand basics, comment accordingly.

Want to get dashboard from `traefik.test.local/dashboard` rather `test.local:8080`, similarly api should be accessed from `traefik.test.local/api`. So that don't have to think about port numbers.

added lines to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       test.local
127.0.0.1       traefik.test.local
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Lets name the container
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      # Enables the web UI
      - "--api.insecure=true" 
      # Tells Traefik to listen to docker
      - "--providers.docker"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    #labels:
      #- "traefik.http.routers.router.rule=Host(`traefik.test.local/dashboard`)"
      #- "traefik.http.routers.router.rule=Host(`traefik.test.local/api`)"
    restart:
      always
```

Not able to understand how to connect from router to services. Also correct me if I am wrong anywhere. Thank you.

PS: OS: kde-neon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using the following definition, you need to add labels for the routers and service and not only the router

```
proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
      - '--entryPoints.metrics.address=:8082'
      - '--providers.providersThrottleDuration=2s'
      - '--providers.docker.watch=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmMode=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmModeRefreshSeconds=15s'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host("traefik.lvh.me")'
      - '--accessLog.bufferingSize=0'
      - '--api=true'
      - '--api.dashboard=true'
      - '--api.insecure=true'
      - '--ping.entryPoint=web'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8080:8080'
    restart:
      always
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=monitoring
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard.rule=Host(`dashboard.traefik.lvh.me`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard.service=traefik-dashboard
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-api.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-api.rule=Host(`api.traefik.lvh.me`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-api.service=traefik-api
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-api.entrypoints=web
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
```

also if you use `lvh.me` domain you not need to edit `/etc/hosts`

Comment: OP probably needs some explanations. +1 for `lvh.me`.

Comment: Replaced `dashboard.traefik.lvh.me` with only `traefik.lvh.me` => `traefik.lvh.me` or `traefik.lvh.me/dashboard` goes to `traefik.lvh.me/dashboard` as asked.

`api.traefik.lvh.me` does not go to anywhere showing connection error. However, `traefik.lvh.me/api/rawdata` shows data.

Thus, not able to grasp the role  of `dashboard.traefik.lvh.me` or `api.traefik.lvh.me`.

Comment: API domain is forwarded to port 80, by default this will show 404 error same as when you fo to HTTP://127.0.0.1:80. what do you try to achieve here and why do you even need this domain ?

Comment: Sorry. I asked bad question. both dashboard and api is indeed serving from port 8080. I am learning. Hope you understand.